# Vue 2 not setting component data when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having a rather strange problem with vue (v2.6.14) in which I am creating a new array based on one receive as a prop. Here's the relevant code:

```
props: { employees: Array },
data() {
  return {
    sortedEmployees: [],
  };
},
mounted() {
  this.sortedEmployees = this.employees.slice(0);
},
```

Essencially what I want here is to create a new reference for the employees array so that I can sort it to display later without actually altering the original array. I am not worried about cloning the actual objects inside the array since I will not alter them.

The problem with this is that, when the app 'hot reloads'(due to some change in the code) it works as expected, the hook is called and the component data is set according to what is expected BUT if I actually refresh the page in the browser, even though the hook is called, the component data is not set and I end up with an empty array. I can solve this by setting up a watcher to the prop and then it would set the data there, but what I am interested here is understanding what's happening. If the hook is called when the page is refreshed why doesn't it set the data properly as it does when 'hot reloading'?

I have a minimal setup created with vue-cli, no fancy configurations whatsoever. Any clue what I might be missing?

Comment: Can you please add a Vue snippet ([<>] icon)? Doesn't seem wrong looking at the source code. I would suggest using a `computed` value for your use-case. Still curious how it works when hot-loading but not when refreshing. I usually have the opposite effect.

Comment: It's `mounted` not `mount`

Comment: @Naren You are right, but in my code it's 'mounted', I misspelled it here.

Comment: Can you create a  reproducible stackblitz link, I don't see any issues with code, I want to see how "employees" being passed.

Comment: Also `slice()` method returns a shallow copies of items.

Comment: In this case I am using slice because I just care about the array reference. Here's a stackblitz, but here I can't get the array at all... https://vue-6vggxl.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the employees are loaded async, right?

I don't know your exact application structure, but the problem is usually the following:

The `mounted` hook gets called, when the component mounts, of course. If the `employees` are loaded async in the parent component, the mount hook is called, before the async call is resolved. So it will copy an empty array at this time.

With a watcher you solve this problem, because the watcher fires as soon as the async call resolves (as it mutates the `employees` array).

Same happens to the hotreload. When the hotreload occurs, the `mounted` hook gets executed again - at this time the `employees` array is already prefilled with values and therefore the correct array is copied in the `mount` hook.

**Update**

If you want to avoid watchers, you could also wrap your component like this:

```html
<your-component
  v-if="employees.length > 0"
  :employees="employees"
/>
```

Be aware, that the copied `employees` array IN your component is still not reactive. It just copies the array on the first time it has more than 1 value. A watcher really makes sense in this case.

If you use watchers, make sure to use the `immediate: true` option. This ensures, that the watcher is also called the first time on render (and also on hotreload).

**Summary**

If you really want to copy the array, use watchers (with the `immediate: true` flag).

If it's just about sorting, go for the computed property solution suggested by @Sebastian Scholl

Comment: Hi, that was what I thought as well, so I just hard coded the data in the mounted hook of the parent component but the behavior is the same. I tried to reproduce it in stackblitz (https://vue-6vggxl.stackblitz.io) but there it doesn't render them at all. The version of vue there is the 3rd but that should not have anything to do.

Comment: You have to hardcode it in the `created` hook. If you hardcode it in the `mounted` hook - like you did in your demo, you have the same problem again, as the component is already rendered. (https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-d3voh1?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: @AntónioQuadrado I've added a workaround - not sure if it fits your case

Comment: Yeah, the watcher is how I solved the case, I just want to understand the different behaviors, because what triggers me is that I have to have both the watcher and the mounted, because in the hot reload only the mounted works and in the refresh only the watcher works and I don't know why is behaving differently.

Comment: You probably should add the `immediate: true` option to the watcher, to make it work on hotreload. The watcher is the proper way to do it, if you really want to copy it. However, if it is really just about the sorting, than go for the computed property version, suggested by @Sebastian Scholl

Comment: With the `immediate: true` it works just with the watcher. I just noticed that the hot reload doesn't trigger the re-rendering of the parent component, so it kind of makes sense now on why it has different behaviours.

Comment: If you want to update your answer with that information I'd be happy to accept it. And thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad that it helped. I've updated my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the component is Refreshing (reseting) with the prop change however it's not Re-mounting. This is what would cause the array to reset to it's default state ([]), whereas on hot-reload the actual page is reloading.

Try the following, and if it doesn't resolver the issue I would suggest going the route of using a Watcher.

```
<template>
  <div>
    sorted: {{ sortedEmployees }}
    <br />
    not sorted: {{ employees }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    employees: Array,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      sortedEmployees: Array.from(this.employees),
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Another approach is to just use a Computed method so and add any filtering/sorting logic inside that method. It would be something like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="sortKey" />
    sorted: {{ sortedEmployees }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    employees: Array,
  },
  data () {
    return {
      sortKey: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sortedEmployees() {
      return Array.from(this.employees).sort(this.sortingFunction);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    sortingFunction(a, b) {
      // sorting function using this.sortKey
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

---

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I switched up the code in the example a little and believe to have gotten it to work as I you're describing.

**App.js**
First off, I made it so that the employees array is updated after 3 seconds.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Dashboard :employees="employees" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App', 

  components: { Dashboard },

  data () {
    return {
      employees: [
        {
          employeeId: '1',
          firstName: 'Leite',
        }
      ]
    };
  },

  methods: {
    updateEmployees () {
      this.employees = this.employees.concat([
        {
          employeeId: '2',
          firstName: 'Jacinto',
          
        },
        {
          employeeId: '3',
          firstName: 'Capelo',
        }
      ]);
    }
  },
  
  mounted () {
    setTimeout(this.updateEmployees, 3000)
  },
};
</script>
```

**Dashboard.js**
The `updated()` lifecycle hook runs whenever data changes are detected (props and data properties). This effectively detected the change in the prop passed by the parent App.js component and re-rendered the data - whereas the `mounted` hook only ran once per page load.

```
<template>
  <div id="dashbord">
    <div
      v-for="(employee, index) in sortedEmployees"
      :key="employee.employeeId"
    >
      {{ employee.firstName }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Dashboard',
  props: { 
    employees: Array 
  },
  data() {
    return {
      sortedEmployees: Array.from(this.employees)
    };
  },
  updated() {
    this.sortedEmployees = Array.from(this.employees)
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but the result is the same.

Comment: See the second example and lmk. If neither of those two work, are you certain that the parent prop is not somehow passing an empty array?

Comment: The problem of the computed property is that I will need to sort the array according to a field, so I would be creating a new array any time this sorting param changed and not only when the data changed. As for the second question, yes, indeed the parent is passing empty array when the mounted hook of child is called (during the refresh, not the hot reload).

Comment: You can still use the computed method and utilize a field for the the sorting function. See example above. I wouldn't worry about the creating of a new array each time as the garbage collection system in Javascript will release the allocated memory each time, being that no array is getting stored in an unique variable/constant.

Can you share more details about the hook/state/API or whatever you're relying on to supply to prop with a non-empty array?

Comment: Still about the computed property, in my scenario there would be a changeable param in which to sort the array with. Using the computed property, the computation would be triggered any time this param changed and not only when the array changed and although it might not be significant it would add unnecessary iterations. As for more details, please check the stackblitz provided in the other answer discussion.

Comment: @AntónioQuadrado I updated the answer, check out the second half. I believe that using the `updated()` hook in the child component is what you were looking for, as opposed to the `mounted()` hook. `updated()` and `beforeUpdate()`  run when data changes.

Comment: Thank you, I can't test it right now but it seems that will end up being pretty similar to the watcher approach. The only thing I wonder is that if for example we have additional props on the component it would not be triggered by all changes and not just the employees prop.