# When I refresh a page in Vue 3 , request is called but the component is not loaded

Tags: asynchronous, request, vuejs3, page-refresh, lifecycle-hook

I have a vue app which is something like this

```
<template>
<div class="text-center">
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">پاسخ</th>
      <th scope="col">سؤال</th>
      <th scope="col">شماره سؤال</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="question in this.questions" :key="question.id-1">
      <th scope="row"><input  class="form-check-input"  type="checkbox"   /></th>
      <td>{{question.question_text}}</td>
      <td>{{question.id-1}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-5" @click="handlsubmit">ثبت پاسخ</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "InitialTest",
  data() {
    return {
      questions: this.$store.state.diagnosis.question
    };
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch("diagnosis/insertQuestion");
  }
```

when it is loaded for the first time, it's okay but when i refresh the page, the request is called but the component doesn't load

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 2 not setting component data when page is refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120390/vue-2-not-setting-component-data-when-page-is-refreshed)

Comment: @Tolbxela checked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. this is the error

Comment: @tripleee I read it and changed the hooks but there was no success.

Comment: @Tolbxela I deleted my extensions and the error is gone now. but the main problem still remains

Comment: @Nana99 this could be something with your setup and is not possible to clear with the provided source code. There is no info about the component and the store. We cannot help you based on provided information.